# Execution of Selenium Script even after Test case fails

Tags: java, selenium, scripting, selenium-webdriver, testcase

Actually I'm trying to run the test cases for a web application in Eclipse using TestNG. But i'm having some problem while running the Selenium Scripts. I just want to continue the execution even though some test cases fails. But i don't know how to do that.

I'm very new to this topic friends. Please Help me..!!! Anyway Thanks in Advance.

Comment: (IMHO) That could create problems later in test maintenance..

Comment: I'm trying to run the code entirely so that i can check how many testcases passed and how much of it failed. Is this possible ?? @Jayan

Comment: are you running test cases that are interdependent?

you can check [TestNg](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#introduction) for any help

Comment: Some of the test cases are interdependent.But i think i can handle that situation.I need this in order to run the scripts that are not interdependent. If u have any idea please tell me sir.!!! @pArAs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the *alwaysRun = true* annotation in TestNG is not going to entirely solve your problem.

In order to allow Selenium to continue even when there is an occasional Exception, you need to define a Wait object with the FluentWait class, like so:

```
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
       .withTimeout(30, SECONDS)
       .pollingEvery(5, SECONDS)
       .ignoring( NoSuchElementException.class, ElementNotFoundException.class );
// using a customized expected condition
WebElement foo1 = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
     public WebElement apply( WebDriver driver ) {
       // do something here if you want
       return driver.findElement( By.id("foo") );
     }
   });
// using a built-in expected condition
WebElement foo2 = wait.until( ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(
     By.id("foo") );
```

This gives you the ability to **ignore** exceptions whenever .findElement is called until a certain pre-configured timeout is reached.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, in that case you need to use one of the attribute of `@Test` Annotation i.e

```
@Test(alwaysRun = true)
```

If set to true, this test method will always be run even if it depends on a method that failed.